# Linear Progress Bar of Image File Upload With Dynamic Values MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, upload, progress

I'm trying to upload pictures , and display progress according to files uploaded.
I'm getting log for every file uploaded,
Suppose i have 7 files and getting 7 logs while uploading, how can i set the percentage of linear progress bar according to it(move the progress)

```
import * as React from "react";
import LinearProgress, {
LinearProgressProps
} from "@mui/material/LinearProgress";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

function LinearProgressWithLabel(
props: LinearProgressProps & { value: number }
) {
 return (
  <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
  <Box sx={{ width: "100%", mr: 1 }}>
    <LinearProgress variant="determinate" {...props} />
  </Box>
  <Box sx={{ minWidth: 35 }}>
    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">{`${Math.round(
      props.value
    )}%`}</Typography>
  </Box>
 </Box>
 );
 }

  export default function LinearWithValueLabel() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(10);

  React.useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
  setProgress((prevProgress) =>
    prevProgress >= 100 ? 10 : prevProgress + 10
  );
   }, 800);
  return () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
 };
 }, []);

 return (
<Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
  <LinearProgressWithLabel value={progress} />
 </Box>
);
}
```

codesandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-fast-8m1ien?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1124

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of an array state which holds the progress of every file you upload. Since this is an example the default state already consists of 7 files with its corresponding progress.

> You might want to set the default value to an empty object `{}` in actual use. This way you can still add the uploaded file progress dynamically as shown in the next step.

```
  const [progressArray, setProgressArray] = React.useState({
    file1: 0,
    file2: 0,
    file3: 0,
    file4: 0,
    file5: 0,
    file6: 0,
    file7: 0
  });
```

Updating that state would look like this, overwriting the corresponding file progress `file1`:

```
  setProgressArray((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    file1: prev.file1 >= 100 ? 10 : prev.file1 + 10
  }));
```

Now inside your `LinearProgress` we sum up all the progress and **divide** it by the number of files to be uploaded in the state. Since this is a division we exclude the empty object state and return 0.

```
  <LinearProgressWithLabel
    value={
      Object.keys(progressArray).length
        ? Object.values(progressArray).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) /
          Object.keys(progressArray).length
        : 0
    }
  />
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit angry-wildflower-vg2rei]